# can't call javascript function in a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've a phtml (magento) with following code:

```
        <? if($discount_amount != ""): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function memberprice () {

            price_text = jQuery('.price-box .price').text();
            price_num = Number(price_text.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
            final_price = price_num - <? echo $discount_amount ?>;

            return '$'+parseFloat(final_price).tofixed(2);

        }
        jQuery('.price-box .price').on("hover", function() {
            new_price = memberprice();
            jQuery('.price-box .price').text(new_price);
        });             

        </script>       
        <? endif ?>
```

when i hover the .price div, the error display in console memberprice

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function kelvinator-3-4-kwn07crd-d.html:1635
memberprice kelvinator-3-4-kwn07crd-d.html:1635
(anonymous function) kelvinator-3-4-kwn07crd-d.html:1639
f.event.special.(anonymous function).handle jquery.js:3
f.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
h.handle.i
```

what the problem about code?

Comment: It is highly unlikely this code can cause such a error

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem, but `tofixed` should be `toFixed`

Comment: @aarontam you are right